# How to Get Head or Last Commit revision of a file in SharpSVN

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I need to read the head version (or last commit) version of a file.

with this approach i get the head version of my working copy,

```
string workingFolder = @"C:\trunk\Projects\XML\English.xml";
SvnWorkingCopyClient workingCopyClient = new SvnWorkingCopyClient();
SvnWorkingCopyVersion version;
workingCopyClient.GetVersion(workingFolder, out version);
MessageBox.Show(version.End.ToString());
```

But i what i want is to get the head version of my working copy of the **file**

Deeply appreciate for your time and help

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684953/how-to-get-latest-revision-number-from-sharpsvn

Comment: All the methods specified in that link gives me the head version of  working copy and not specific to a file

Answer (score 0):

It is the same way as retrieving revisions for a directory:

```
public long GetfFileRevision(string path) {
        using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient()) {
        SvnInfoEventArgs info;
        try {
            client.GetInfo(path, out info);
            if (info.Revision >= 0) return info.Revision;
        } catch (Exception) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```