# How do I get the top revision number for a branch from SVN repository?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharpsvn

I'm using this code snippet for finding top revision number from **svn** but my page is not responding. It keeps on searching only

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    SvnInfoEventArgs info;
    Uri repos = new Uri("svn://india01/repository/branches/mybranch1");
    client.GetInfo(repos, out info);
    lblMsg.Visible = true;
    lblMsg.Text = (string.Format("The last revision of {0} is {1}", 
           repos, info.Revision));
}
```

I want to fetch the top revision number from the `mybranch1` which is in the **svn** repository at `svn://india01/repository/branches/mybranch1`.

Comment: Have you tried using http:// instead of the svn:// protocol?

Comment: can i use http:// protocol at place of svn:// protocol?

Comment: Yes, eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/685010/43846

Comment: but after running web page it's looking for a file as below
f:\qqn\sharpsvn-dist\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp

Comment: after changing the protocol from SVN:// to Http:// showing below error
`http://india01/repository/branches/mybranch1': could not connect to server `http://india01/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we need to add the SharpSvn Api dll reference into c# project.
[link for SharpSvn package download](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net) and 
[then follow the below link for example](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm)
code for getting top revision number

```
SvnInfoEventArgs statuses;
SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.Clear();//clear a previous authentication
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usr", "pass");
client.GetInfo("svn://india00/Repo/branches/xyz", out statuses);
int LastRevision = (int)statuses.LastChangeRevision;`
```

add references as

```
using SharpSvn;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`
```