# In SharpSvn, what's SvnClient.getinfo return value?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

In SharpSvn's documentation I found ([here](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_GetInfo_1.htm)), the return value of `SvnClient.getinfo` (`boolean` type) is missing. Can anyone help with that?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to send a mail at the bottom of page which `Send comments on this topic to SharpSvn Users` part. You might get a faster answer..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the answer I got:

> Usually all SvnClient methods return true on success and throw an
>   error on failures. But if you change .ThrowOnError to false or cancel
>   a command in its eventhandler then it will return false on an
>   error/cancel.   So if you are just using a simple call to .GetInfo
>   without an SvnInfoArgs object with specific settings (or very specific
>   handling on the SvnClient instance itself where you can also override
>   the error handling) you can ignore the return value as it will always
>   be true.

The credit goes to a helpful guy named Bert who sent me this email. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It takes an out param of [SvnInfoEventArgs](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/T_SharpSvn_SvnInfoEventArgs.htm) which gets populated of the call was a success. For example, I might use the GetInfo call to [get the most recent revision number from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684953/how-to-get-latest-revision-number-from-sharpsvn):

```
private long GetLatestRevisionNumber(Uri myUri)
{
    using (SvnClient client = GetClient())
    {
        SvnInfoEventArgs info;
        client.GetInfo(myUri, out info);
        return info.LastChangeRevision;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about the bool return value, not the out parameter. And it's answered already