# How to get revision date time using sharpsvn (working copy)

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I need to get the date/time when the revision was commited, Now I can get last revision but not finding how to get the date and time when this revision created.
This is my code now.

```
Int32 LastRevision;
var workingCopyClient = new SvnWorkingCopyClient();
SvnWorkingCopyVersion version;
workingCopyClient.GetVersion(RootFolder, out version);
LastRevision = version.End;
workingCopyClient.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the SvnClient class? There's a couple of options you have with that:

Firstly: [How to get latest revision number from SharpSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684953/how-to-get-latest-revision-number-from-sharpsvn)

or this:

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())    
{
    Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> logEventArgs;
    SvnLogArgs logArgs = new SvnLogArgs
        {
            Limit = 1
        };

    client.GetLog(target, logArgs, out logEventArgs);

    DateTime revisionTime = logEventArgs[0].Time;
}
```